# Want to change application icon when desktop size Changed

Tags: c#, wpf, icons

I Want to change application icon when desktop size Changed.Please see the picture i want to update my application icon whenever user change size. Currently i am using 256*256 icon when ever user change size it become blurred.

Comment: can u show what u have tried so far.

Comment: currently i add icon file in icon and manifest file. It was working fine.But now i want to change application icon dynamically when desktop size changed

Answer (score 0):

get parent window size using an event handler.

```
Rectangle resolution = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
```

Then set the icon according to the parent window size

```
If(resolution> "expected size")
{
 ico = ico_small;
}
```